How to get a dynamic list to display horizontal in a grid fashion
I want to display dynamic list of cards horizontally. The large will be 3 by 3 for each row then in small screens it will be full column 12.

<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
</ul>

. Each list item still is vertical and not horizontal
 <ion-grid> 
  <ion-list class="ion-padding-top">
    @for (item of myList; track item.userId)
     {
       <ion-row>
         <ion-card class="col-4">
           <ion-avatar>
            <img alt="Silhouette of a person's head" src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/img/demos/avatar.svg" />
           </ion-avatar>
           <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>Card Title</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle>Card Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
           </ion-card-header>
        
           <ion-card-content>
            Here's a small text description for the card content. Nothing more, nothing less.
           </ion-card-content>
         </ion-card>
        </ion-row> 
     }    
    }
  </ion-list>
</ion-grid>


you can use ionic grid to make your columns responsive:
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
   @for (item of myList; track item.userId){
    <ion-col size-lg="3" size-md="3" size-sm="12" size="12"> // to make it responsive you can adjust these size values. 
      <ion-card>
        //your card content here
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
   }
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

For more info you can check documentation: Ion-Grid

Where should I put the dynamic list to get the desired effect of the first image?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.list-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.list-group-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A forth item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A fofth item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A sixth item</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>


here is the output

[i think this code will help you][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/UepQw.png

You did nothing in here(just added ) nor used the user ionic to do grid.
